# How do I open a form in a method if passed its name as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a standard method to open a form based on the parameter passed to it. Basically, to get this done:

```
using (Quotes newQte = new Quotes())
{
    newQte.ShowDialog();
}
```

by replacing:

```
Quotes with a passed parameter, e.g. FormToOpen.
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: What do you mean by _replacing Quotes with a passed parameter, e.g. FormToOpen_?

Comment: I mean the parameter containing the name of the form to be opened, or a (proper) reference to it.

Comment: Do you want to pass in a string (not type-safe) like `"FormToOpen"`, or do you want to pass in an instance of a `Func` delegate, like `() => new FormToOpen()`.

Comment: I am not sure which is best. The goal is to have a standard method that will accept a reference to a form and then open that form.  So, I could use it to open Quotes and then after that use the same method to open the StockEdit form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using a "[Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method)" to do so.

You would define FormToOpen like this (I'm renaming it to `createForm()` for clarity):

```
Func<Form> createForm;
```

So the code would look something like this:

```
private void MakeAndDisplayForm(Func<Form> createForm)
{
    using (var form = createForm())
    {
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
MakeAndDisplayForm(() => new MyForm());
```

Where `MyForm` is the type of form that you want `MakeAndDisplayForm()` to create.

It's fairly common to do this kind of thing; often you pass the creator function to the constructor of a class. Then that class uses the creator function later on to create things that it can use, without knowing how they were created.

This is a form of [Depencency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

(*Disclaimer: All error checking elided for brevity*)

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks very much. This is exactly what I needed. Matthew you are my hero!

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that creates the form you want to display, based on a parameter:

```
public static Form CreateAppropriateForm(int formToOpen)
{
    switch (formToOpen) {
        case 0:
            return new Quotes();
        case 1:
            return new Citations();
        case 2:
            return new References();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter value.");
    }
}
```

Where `Quotes`, `Citations` and `References` would be your form classes, derived from `Form`.

Then, you could invoke that method when you want to show your form:

```
using (Form form = CreateAppropriateForm(2)) {
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Here shown with the example of value `2` - but you are free to insert any other expression that yields a value usable for your form selection method there.

Of course, you can also declare `formToOpen` in a more meaningful way, if that is suitable for your application. For example, you can declare it as a custom `enum` type, where each `enum` value denotes a particular form.

Comment: Thanks very much for your valuable input!