# How do I pass the name of a form to a method that would instatiate it and set some properties of it?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I want to make a method that I can pass the name of a form to, and that method would instantiate the form and set it's position.

So I would call it like:

OpenNewForm("Login");

the method would look something like:

```
Public void OpenNewForm(string sForm)
{
[sForm] frm = new [sForm];
frm.Parent = parent;
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
frm.ShowDialog();

}
```

But I dont know how to refer to the variable sForm as part of the instatiation code.

Comment: You can do that either with reflection or with a generic method.

Comment: Oops.  I found an answer in another stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639777/how-do-i-open-a-form-in-a-method-if-passed-its-name-as-a-parameter

Comment: That must be the generic method of which you speak.  I am new to delegates so this is great to see how it is used.  Thanks HighCore.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance().  Just the class name isn't enough, you need to know the namespace name as well.  And ought to know what assembly it lives in.  Do favor the typeof keyword instead.

Comment: Why not pass a typeof(object)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple method (adapted from

```
public static void OpenNewForm(string formName)
{
    Form frm;
    switch (formName) {
        case "Login":
            frm = new Login();
        case "Citations":
            frm = new Citations();
        case "References":
            frm = new References();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter value.");
    }

    frm.Parent = parent;
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void OpenNewForm(string formName)
{
    string myNamespace = App.Current.GetType().ToString().Split('.')[0]; // TODO: Improve this method of get the namespace.

    var w = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(null, myNamespace + "." + formName).Unwrap();
    w.Show();
}
```